# How to update data with SharedFlow in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

In my application I want update data with **SharedFlow** and my application architecture is **MVI** . 
I write below code, but just update one of data!
I have 2 `spinners` and this `spinners` data fill in **viewmodel**.
**ViewModel code :**

```
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: DetailRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<MyState>(MyState.Idle)
    val state: StateFlow<MyState> get() = _state

    fun handleIntent(intent: MyIntent) {
        when (intent) {
            is MyIntent.CategoriesList -> fetchingCategoriesList()
            is MyIntent.PriorityList -> fetchingPrioritiesList()
        }
    }

    private fun fetchingCategoriesList() {
        val data = mutableListOf(Car, Animal, Color, Food)
        _state.value = DetailState.CategoriesData(data)
    }

    private fun fetchingPrioritiesList() {
        val data = mutableListOf(Low, Normal, High)
        _state.value = DetailState.PriorityData(data)
    }
}
```

With below codes I filled spinners in fragment :

```
     lifecycleScope.launch {
                //Send
                viewModel.handleIntent(MyIntent.CategoriesList)
                viewModel.handleIntent(MyIntent.PriorityList)
                //Get
                viewModel.state.collect { state ->
                    when (state) {
                        is DetailState.Idle -> {}
                        is DetailState.CategoriesData -> {
                            categoriesList.addAll(state.categoriesData)
                            categorySpinner.setupListWithAdapter(state.categoriesData) { itItem ->
                                category = itItem
                            }
                            Log.e("DetailLog","1")
                        }
                        is DetailState.PriorityData -> {
                            prioritiesList.addAll(state.prioritiesData)
                            prioritySpinner.setupListWithAdapter(state.prioritiesData) { itItem ->
                                priority = itItem
                            }
                            Log.e("DetailLog","2")
                        }
}
```

When run application not show me **number 1** in `logcat`, just show **number 2**.
Not call this line : `is DetailState.CategoriesData`

But when comment this line `viewModel.handleIntent(MyIntent.PriorityList)` show me **number 1** in **logcat**!

Why when use this code `viewModel.handleIntent(MyIntent.CategoriesList) viewModel.handleIntent(MyIntent.PriorityList)` not show **number 1** and **2** in logcat ?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS thanks my friend, I change it and again result is such as previous !

Comment: Can you make your funcitons `suspend` and then use emit with `viewModelScope.launch{ _uiState.emit(...)` on both methods? fetchingCategoriesList and fetchingPrioritiesList? if it doesn't work, try to add a delay in between viewModel.handleIntent(MyIntent.CategoriesList) and viewModel.handleIntent(MyIntent.priorityList) to check if it's that the problem

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS , **in viewModel :**  
`private suspend fun fetchingCategoriesList() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val data = mutableListOf(Car, Animal, Color, Food)
        _state.emit(DetailState.CategoriesData(data))
    }

    private suspend fun fetchingPrioritiesList() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val data = mutableListOf(Low, Normal, High)
        _state.emit(DetailState.PriorityData(data))
    }`

Comment: **fragment is :**  `lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewModel.handleIntent(DetailIntent.CategoriesList)
                viewModel.handleIntent(DetailIntent.PriorityList)` but result like previous !

Comment: Do you have this project public on github or somewhere else? So I can check it?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS thanks my friend. do you help free time for connect to my system with Anydesk?

Comment: can't do this, I do prefer you to upload it to github or somewhere so I can check and see the problem if possible :)

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS , please wait for upload it . thanks

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS my files is here : https://www.mediafire.com/file/ryp24b1h2bedexw/note.zip/file please help me

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS , I added delay it's fix. my code is: `private suspend fun fetchingPrioritiesList() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val data = mutableListOf(HIGH, NORMAL, LOW)
        delay(50)
        _state.emit(DetailState.PriorityData(data))
    }` but I want to know this way is good? is this good practice or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248556/discussion-between-skizo-oziks-and-dr-keyok).

Comment: @Dr.KeyOk, definitely not good practice! You’re using the wrong tool for the job, which results in a race condition and then hacking at the race condition with artificial delays which is not a foolproof solution and makes your app less responsive. You shouldn’t use StateFlow for this in the first place.

Comment: @Tenfour04 What can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a StateFlow is *conflated*, meaning if you rapidly change its value faster than collectors can collect it, old values are dropped without ever being collected. Therefore, StateFlow is not suited for an event-like system like this. After all, it’s in the name that it is for states rather than events.

It’s hard to suggest an alternative because your current code looks like you shouldn’t be using Flows at all. You could simply call a function that synchronously returns data that you use synchronously. I don’t know if your current code is a stepping stone towards something more complicated that really would be suitable for flows.

Comment: Thanks you my friend for your help. can you send to me code for how can I fix it? please

Comment: Like I said, I don’t know enough about what you’re doing or building to know what the correct solution is for you. Probably either just turning these into plain functions that directly return the data (no flow), or separate flows for each type of data.

Comment: I used LiveData instead of SharedFlow and remove delay code! After remove delay codes again show me just one of spinner and other spinner is empty!

Comment: LiveData is very similar to StateFlow. It is also for updating a singular state, which means you only ever care about the latest change. So it is not appropriate for this either. I don’t understand why you’re trying to run two separate pieces of data through the same flow (or LiveData). It just doesn’t make sense to try to do that. They should each have their own flow (or LiveData).

Comment: I have 2 spinners and I should these spinners with data. I filled this data from viewmodel. I used MVI and for this I need to State and Intent classes. I think for fill spinners do not need for flow because and removed suspend methods from this. but again, show me just one of spinners data !

Comment: You need a separate Flow for each spinner. It does not make sense to use a single Flow for two different spinners unless that Flow is a flow of some class that wraps multiple lists at once.

Comment: I looked up MVI because I was not familiar with it. I think you're misapplying the concept. If CategoriesList and PrioritiesList are both supposed to be on screen at the same time, they shouldn't be passed as different versions of the same Intent. You're passing them through the same Flow, which implies that you only want one or the other. An Intent should represent an overall state for the screen you want to show or a section of the screen. So if you have a screen that shows two spinners you would have something like `Intent.MyTwoSpinnersScreen` and then the ViewModel would have a

Comment: Flow of some class that wraps both lists into one object.

Comment: Really thaaaaaaanks my friend! Now I know MVI means! thanks <3 . I fixed it with **Intent.MyTwoSpinnersScreen** way . Thanks for your help and time